# Control the pip version in virtualenv

Tags: python, pip, virtualenv, python-wheel, python-venv

How do I control the version of `pip` which is used in a freshly created [`venv`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html)?

By default, it uses a [vendored pip distribution](https://github.com/python/cpython/tree/master/Lib/ensurepip/_bundled) which may be out of date or unsuitable for whatever other reason. I want to be able to create a `venv` with a user-specified version of pip installed *initially*, as opposed to creating one and then upgrading the pip installation from within the env.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since Python 3.9 the stdlib [`venv`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html) module has [`EnvBuilder.upgrade_dependencies`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html#venv.EnvBuilder.upgrade_dependencies). Unfortunately, it has two shortcomings:

- Won't really help users to install a *specific* pip version, only the latest.
- It still installs the vendored pip and setuptools versions first, and then uninstall them if they're outdated, which they almost always will be in practice.

It would be ideal to install the latest versions directly! The `venv` CLI provides a `--without-pip` argument that is useful here. You can use this to opt-out of the vendored pip, and then actually use the vendored pip wheel to install your desired pip version instead (along with any other packages you might want in a freshly created virtual environment).

It's best to put it into a function - this goes into your shell profile or rc file:

```bash
function ve() {
    local py="python3"
    if [ ! -d ./.venv ]; then
        echo "creating venv..."
        if ! $py -m venv .venv --prompt=$(basename $PWD) --without-pip; then
            echo "ERROR: Problem creating venv" >&2
            return 1
        else
            local whl=$($py -c "import pathlib, ensurepip; [whl] = pathlib.Path(ensurepip.__path__[0]).glob('_bundled/pip*.whl'); print(whl)")
            echo "boostrapping pip using $whl"
            .venv/bin/python $whl/pip install --upgrade pip setuptools wheel
            source .venv/bin/activate
        fi
    else
        source .venv/bin/activate
    fi
}
```

As written, this function just pulls latest `pip`, `setuptools`, and `wheel` from index. To force specific versions you can just change this line of the shell script:

```
.venv/bin/python $whl/pip install --upgrade pip setuptools wheel
```

Into this, for example:

```
.venv/bin/python $whl/pip install pip==19.3.1
```

For Python 2.7 users, you may do a similar trick because `virtualenv` provides similar command-line options in `--no-pip`, `--no-setuptools`, and `--no-wheel`, and there is still a vendored pip wheel available to bootstrap [since Python 2.7.9](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ensurepip.html). Pathlib will not be available, so you'll need to change the `pathlib` usage into `os.path` + [`glob`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html).

Answer (score 17):

For me, I just upgraded pip/virtualenv/virtualenvwrapper on my machine (not inside the virtualenv). Subsequently created virtualenvs had the updated version.

```
deactivate
pip install --upgrade pip virtualenv virtualenvwrapper
mkvirtualenv ...
```

Answer (score 15):

From reading the source of virtualenv, it looks like pip is installed from a source tarfile included with virtualenv. In virtualenv 1.10.1, it is `pip-1.4.1.tar.gz` in the `site-packages/virtualenv_support` directory (it gets `setuptools` from the same place). You could feasibly replace that archive to control the version; virtualenv.py, at least the version I have, doesn't care which version of pip is there:

```
    if not no_pip:
        install_sdist('Pip', 'pip-*.tar.gz', py_executable, search_dirs)
```

You could also pass the `--no-pip` option and then install the version you want from source.

In virtualenv 1.11, it looks for a wheel file (e.g. `pip-*.whl`) instead of a `tar.gz`, but other than that it acts the same way (thanks @wim for the update).

Comment: This is true in virtualenv `1.10.1`, but in `1.11` it no longer searches for a .tar.gz, instead they get pip from a [wheel file](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0427/).

Comment: Would have been nice if you (@Sam Hartsfield) had posted the link to the source file.

Answer (score 14):

You cannot *downgrade* pip using pip, the solution is to install a specific version in your virtual environment:

```
virtualenv env -p python3.6 --no-pip
source env/bin/activate
curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py -o get-pip.py
python get-pip.py pip==18.1
```

This will allow you to keep using `--process-dependency-links` that was removed in pip 19.

Comment: You can downgrade pip using pip.

Comment: @wim not if pip doesn't work.  pip 21 does not work with python 3.5 yet it gets installed when i create a virtualenv

Comment: looking over that get-pip.py, it's a giant binary filed stuffed into a python file.  I have no idea what it really does, but it looks fishy.

Comment: @rtaft  Pip v21 would not be installed for Python 3.5 in the first place, because it's not supported. Python 3.5 is now end-of-life anyway.

Comment: @wim I understand its EOL, unfortunately still stuck on it for now.  With Ubuntu 16, it still fails because virtualenv installs pip 21 even though its not supported with python 3.5, which is why I went looking here for how to fix.  It shouldn't but it does.

Comment: @rtaft Hmm, that sounds like a bug in virtualenv then.  Regardless, you should not use virtualenv with Python 3.5, since there is stdlib [`venv`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html) since Python 3.3.

Comment: @wim thank you, using that method uses the pip installed in /usr/lib, which I can then upgrade the venv pip to 20.3.4 using that pip.

Comment: If like me you are working on RHEL/CentOS and the yum provided virtualenv has an ANCIENT non-functional pip, you can use this (without the -p python3.6) and adding `/pip/2.7/` between the domain and the `get-pip.py`. The newest valid pip for 2.7/<3.6 is 20.x, so `'pip<21'` as the argument to `get-pip.py` will get you the best one available.

Comment: --no-pip saved my life

Answer (score 4):

It's easy enough to replace the pip that gets installed in your virtual environment.  Within your virtual environment active, simply execute the following command:

```
pip install pip==1.4.1
```

Comment: This will only work if your currently installed version of pip works.  Sadly, this is not always the case as for example when using a legacy version of Python.

Comment: Doesn't address the question asked.  The point is that one has to do this every time a new virtualenv is created, which is tiresome.

Comment: It doesn't answer to the question

Comment: Yes, I'm having the same problem and would like to not have to install latest pip every time I set up a new venv

Answer (score 0):

While creating virtual environment using **venv** module, use optional argument **--upgrade-deps**.

That will upgrade pip + setuptools to the latest on PyPI.

**Example :** python3 -m venv --upgrade-deps .venv

**Reference link :**
[venv module documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html)

It indicates "Changed in version 3.9: Add --upgrade-deps option to upgrade pip + setuptools to the latest on PyPI"

*Note :* I tried this using Python 3.10.4

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn’t control the pip version installed _initially_, so it doesn’t answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

Solved the same issue today on my windows machine with python 3.10.2 installed.

1. download required pip wheel from [history](https://pypi.org/project/pip/#history) to path\to\python\lib\ensurepip\bundled
2. in path\to\python\lib\ensurepip\__init__.py change `_PIP_VERSION = your version`
3. create environment as usual `python -m venv path\to\env`

Answer (score 0):

I had issues with pip 22.3.1, so I wanted to downgrade it to 22.3, while pip 22.3.1 produces errors and not letting me downgrade as the other solutions suggest.

I solved the issue by creating a new venv with the specific pip version, as follows:

`virtualenv env -p python3.10 --pip 22.3`

Answer (score -1):

**TLDR**

`python -m pip install --upgrade pip==<target version number>`

**Example**

Downgrading from `pip 20.3` to `pip 19.3` from within a virtual environment.

```
(env) $ pip --version
pip 20.3.1

(env) $ python -m pip install --upgrade pip==19.3          # downgrading
Collecting pip==19.3
  Using cached pip-19.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl (1.4 MB)
Installing collected packages: pip
  Attempting uninstall: pip
    Found existing installation: pip 20.3.1
    Uninstalling pip-20.3.1:
      Successfully uninstalled pip-20.3.1
Successfully installed pip-19.3

(env) $pip --version                                                                     trex@Tobiahs-MacBook-Pro
pip 19.3
```

Comment: This is effectively the same as [Wolf's Jan 2014 answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21099267/674039).

Comment: Yeah it's similar, however i felt the `upgrade` keyword to effectively `downgrade` was very counter-intuitive and worth explicitly showing. Cheers.

Comment: You don't need the `--upgrade` keyword here.  `python -m pip install pip==19.3` would work just the same.