# Scripting Python dev env setup

Tags: python

I have created a collection of Python scripts, to be used as tools in our dev group. The scripts have dependencies, such as `requests` and `flake8` (this should technically be under `dev` setup, but whatever).

I have created a `setup-dev.bat` file, with the idea of being a "first-use" setup.

```
python -m pip install --upgrade pip --user
python -m pip install --upgrade virtualenv --user
python -m venv .env
call .\.env\Scripts\Activate.bat
python -m pip install --upgrade pip --user
python -m pip install --upgrade virtualenv --user
pip install .
```

The idea is:

1. Install and/or upgrade `pip` on the system
2. Install and/or upgrade `virtualenv` on the system
3. Create a virtual environment `.env`
4. Activate it
5. Upgrade the `pip` and `virtualenv` under it (not sure if this makes sense at all)
6. 'Install' the scripts - most importantly, this install the dependencies

Now the scripts are ready to use and their dependencies are contained within `.env`. The idea is - if/when those scripts get distributed to the higher environments for Ops to run, I don't want to pollute their environment with my dependencies.

I should point out that those tools will never be distributed over `pip` or any other system, they are for internal use within the company and will be hosted on a source control, or emailed to Operations with execution instructions.

Now my questions:

1. Does this even make sense?
2. Have I unintentionally created a dependency on Windows? In step `4` above I should probably run just `\activate` instead of the `.bat`? I guess the `.env` depends on the host system and would have different contents under a different OS? Which script do I have to call to activate the environment in most OS-agnostic way? The `activate`, the `ps1` or the `.bat`?
3. After the users of my scripts have set it up for first time, I guess they should be educated that if they want to run the scripts, they'd first have to run `.env\Scripts\activate`? Is there any way to semi-automate this, make it more obvious or fool-proof?
4. Why do I get `You are using pip version 19.0.3, however version 19.3.1 is available.` as a result of my `pip upgrade` command?!

Edits:

- I've changed `python -m pip install --upgrade pip --user` to `python -m pip install --upgrade pip` and this got rid of the error. I guess installing "for the user" under the `venv` doesn't make sense anyway.
- I got rid of the `virtualenv` steps, per the comment below
- Changed `pip install .` to `pip install -e .` to ensure that the scripts (some of which act as configurations) are still editable.

I feel like I am progressing, but I am confused about the lack of posts around such setup and it feels like I am doing something wrong.

Comment: You should just create the env with the latest pip version from the get-go - see accepted answer on [Control the pip version in virtualenv](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21099057/674039) about that.  And you don't need to install `virtualenv` at all these days, because of stdlib [`venv`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html).

Comment: oh, OK, I will get rid of the `virtualenv` steps then

Comment: Sounds like you want something like [pipenv](https://github.com/pypa/pipenv).

Answer (score 1):

You could bundle the scripts in a wheel file (read about *entry_points* [here](https://packaging.python.org/guides/distributing-packages-using-setuptools/#scripts)) that can be installed via pip (i.e., `pip install bundle.whl`; see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28002897/wheel-file-installation)).  With this approach, the dependencies will be part of the wheel file and pip will automatically install the dependencies when the wheel file is installed.

`--user` flag to pip will install the scripts in a location local to the user as determined by [the user scheme](https://docs.python.org/3/install/index.html#alternate-installation-the-user-scheme).  So, if you are fine with the scripts "polluting" a user's local installation, then virtualenv is not needed.